# How to communicate between different case situation in erlang case

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
test(Tester) ->
  case Tester of
         start -> X = 4 
         ok -> X = X + 5,
               Y = X/5;
         terminate -> Y
  end.
```

But not exactly this. I Know it can be achieved with tail or simple recursion.
normally X and Y are unbound.

Is there any way to communicate between these cases without the usage of erlang global variables?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You got 2 answers and conclude that you cannot do what you want to achieve with erlang. This is unlikely the truth, but as the code snippet is just invalid erlang, nobody can really help you. A description of the problem you want to solve with an example of code in another language or pseudo code and/or a set of test cases (test(start) returns 4; test(ok) returns 1.8; test(terminate) returns ???) would allow us to help you.

Comment: I edited the question Now look well at my post.I will like to have a function that when i send the atom start it initializes X to 4 and when ever  i send the atom ok a parameter it adds 5 to the previous X and  finally when i send the atom terminate it should return Y.

Answer (score 5):

Erlang is a functional language it means we don't *communicate* between different parts of the code or store values in variables without purpose, we just compute to return value (and sometimes make some sideeffect). If we have common computation in different branches of code we can simply place it in common function.

```
test(Tester) ->
  case Tester of
         start     -> 4;
         ok        -> computeY();
         terminate -> computeY()
  end.

computeY() ->
    X = 4 + 5,
    X/5.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your solutions ..The solutions given above let me understand that what i really want is not possible with erlang.

Comment: It's a great description for functional language!

Answer (score 4):

If you need to access a variable in any clause body of a `case` statement, You have to assign it before `case` statement or **sometimes** you can assign it in `case` clause pattern:

```
test(Arg) ->
    Size = get_size(Arg), % I will use 'Size' in each clause body
    case Arg of
        #{foo := Foo} -> % if Arg is an Erlang map and has key 'foo'
            % I can use 'Foo' only here:
            io:format("It's a map with size ~p and has key foo with value ~p\n", [Size, Foo]);
        [Baz|_] -> % if Arg is an Erlang list with at least one element
            % I can use 'Baz' only here and for example i can NOT use 'Foo' here:
            io:format("It's a list with size ~p and its first element is ~p\n", [Size, Baz]);
        _ ->
            io:format("Unwanted argument ~p with ~p size\n", [Arg, Size])
    end.

get_size(X) when is_map(X)  -> map_size(X);
get_size(X) when is_list(X) -> length(X);
get_size(_)                 -> unknown.
```

I put above code in an Erlang `fun` named `Test` to using it in shell without need to compile a module file:

```
1> Test([5,4,3,2,1]).
It's a list with size 5 and its first element is 5
ok

2> Test(#{key => value, foo => ':)'}).
It's a map with size 2 and has key foo with value ':)'
ok

3> Test([]).                          
Unwanted argument [] with 0 size
ok

4> Test(#{key => value}).             
Unwanted argument #{key => value} with 1 size
ok

5> Test(13).              
Unwanted argument 13 with unknown size
ok
```

If you are curious about variable binding in case, I recommend to read [**this article**](https://medium.com/erlang-battleground/tricky-question-25a956298b9d)

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Erlang you would start (spawn) a process that would hold X in memory as well as the PID (process id) of the process it is supposed to reply to unless you want to pass it a different PID every time along with start/ok/terminate. Processes in Erlang have their own memory, state or loopData. After you spawn a process that knows how to handle specific messages, you pass it the messages and it replies by sending a message back.

```
start_test() ->
  TestPID = spawn(?MODULE, test, [self()]),
  TestPID ! start,
  receive
    X -> io:format("X is: ~p~n",[X]
  end,
  TestPID ! ok,
  receive
    {X,Y} -> io:format("X is: ~p, Y is: ~p~n",[X, Y]
  end,
  TestPID ! terminate,
  receive
    Y -> io:format("Y is: ~p~n",[Y]
  end.

test(PID) -> 
  receive
   start -> PID ! 4,
     test(4, undefined, PID);
   terminate -> undefined
  end.

test(X, Y, PID) ->
  receive
    ok -> PID ! {X+5, (X+5)/5},
      test(X+5, (X+5)/5, PID);
    terminate -> PID ! Y
  end.
```

Don't forget to create a module and export start_test/0 and test/1

If you run start_test() you should get an output of

```
X is: 4
X is: 9, Y is: 1.8
Y is: 1.8
```